# How to show layout on the bottom of ListView

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a layout xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:maxWidth="71dip"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_top" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:maxHeight="70dip"
    android:src="@drawable/registeration_title" >
</ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" >
</TextView>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/informationFrame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:src="@drawable/registeration_info1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/IDNumberTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="26dip"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textgreen" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/EnableDateTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="7dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="140dip"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textColor="@drawable/textgreen" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/linearframe"
        android:text=" " />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buy_in_60" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/imageView5"
        android:layout_below="@id/imageView5" >

    </ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" " />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/listView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="79dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/registeration_info2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/VersionTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dip"
            android:text="Version: 1.0"
            android:textColor="@drawable/darkgreen" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RevisionTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"
        android:text="Revision: 16"
        android:textColor="@drawable/darkgreen" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

some layouts below the ListView in the xml will disappear on the screen

and I tried to put the ListView and other layouts below the ListView into a scrollView

but the ListView will shrink, it looks too small, so i remove the ScrollView,

how should i do to let them appear on the screen without ScrollView?

Comment: I'd play around with the weight attribute, it should solve your issue.

Comment: since you are using scroll view why don't you use wrap_content on your listview height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `Weight` to your layouts like this way..

like you can set ListView Weight is= 0.80 and Bottom View is = 0.20 make sure parent Linear layout Weight sum is = 1.

You can see this is my xml file having List View (80% screen) and bottom Bar layout for Google Ads (almost 20% screen).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layVrt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.72"
        android:weightSum="1">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listViewGame"
            android:textFilterEnabled="true"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.73"></ListView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_white"
        android:paddingLeft="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="3dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:id="@+id/layoutAdMobList">

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

so this will be the output..

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you can try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar" >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_bar"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/slider_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_toggle_button" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/list_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_left_button" />

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/map_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bottom_right_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Place everything inside a RelativeLayout and use android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_bar" on the ListView